# How to make NetworkManager NOT manage libvirtd's virtbr0 and vnet0 interfaces?

Tags: network-manager, virtualization

The libvirt-bin daemon `libvirtd` creates virtual bridge(s) and interface(s) for the virtual machines it controls. NetworkManager kills these connections. I know that it is possible to uninstall or disable NetworkManager, but I wish to use it to manage the real interfaces on my system. I also know that it may be possible to add lines to `/etc/network/interfaces`; however, since libvirtd creates its interfaces dynamically, this seems a poor solution.

How does one make network manager ignore all interfaces EXCEPT eth0 and wlan0?